# Pycharm can't understand modelcaffe file

Tags: python, pycharm, caffe, mobilenet

i was trying to use MobileNet SSD model for Object detection project, and i wanted to use a caffemodel with prototxt file and i downloaded these files from [here](https://github.com/jideilori/mobilenetssd).
After i downloaded files and put them in the same directory of my project, pycharm interpreter can't understand the caffemodel file as shown in the image [issue_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWWnR.png)

Here is the code i use in my object detection project:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image_path = 'roompeople.jpg'
prototxt_path = 'models/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt'
model_path = 'models/mobilenet.caffemodel'

min_confidence = 0.2

classes = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat", "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow",
           "diningtable", "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep", "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]

np.random.seed(543210)
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt_path, model_path)

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
height, width = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300,300)), 0.007, (300, 300), 130)

net.setInput(blob)
detected_objects = net.forward()

print(detected_objects[0][0][0])
```

and Here is the error i got after run the code:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1138: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "models/mobilenet.caffemodel" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile'
```

Comment: Did you expect PyCharm to know what to do with a `.caffemodel` file? Do you have a specific plugin you're using that would enable some functionality? As far as I can see PyCharm just sees that as any old binary file that it's not supposed to understand, and I would agree that's the expected behavior for PyCharm.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidParks i have edited the question and add the code i used with the error i got after running the code, Thank you for ur help.

Comment: Is that just a file not found error by chance? E.g. a path issue?

Comment: No, these files are in the same path of the project and it is shown in the image above 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWWnR.png

Comment: I think the problem is that pycharm can't understand the caffemodel file, either it is a problem in pycharm or in the caffemodel file itself.